# Join Hours and Minute column for showing in Decimal format SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, date-difference

I have two `datetime` columns in a SQL Server table:

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+
| CompLast_SignON_datetime | comp_accidentdate_time |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
| 16-12-2021 04:08         | 16-12-2021 05:10       |
| 17-12-2021 14:20         | 17-12-2021 20:00       |
| 18-12-2021 12:15         | 18-12-2021 15:25       |
| 22-12-2021 06:00         | 22-12-2021 12:34       |
| 25-12-2021 11:30         | 25-12-2021 21:40       |
| 26-12-2021 21:00         | 27-12-2021 02:50       |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

From which I have separated hours and minutes through SQL query

```
SELECT 
    CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time, 
    CONVERT(INT, ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) / 60), 2, 1)) AS 'Hours', 
    FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) - CONVERT(INT, (ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) / 60), 2, 1)) * 60)), '00') AS 'Minutes' 
FROM Safety_SIMS
```

The output is

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------+
| CompLast_SignON_datetime | comp_accidentdate_time | Hours | Minutes |
+--------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------+
| 16-12-2021 04:08         | 16-12-2021 05:10       |     1 |      02 |
| 17-12-2021 14:20         | 17-12-2021 20:00       |     5 |      40 |
| 18-12-2021 12:15         | 18-12-2021 15:25       |     3 |      10 |
| 22-12-2021 06:00         | 22-12-2021 12:34       |     6 |      34 |
| 25-12-2021 11:30         | 25-12-2021 21:40       |    10 |      10 |
| 26-12-2021 21:00         | 27-12-2021 02:50       |     5 |      50 |
+--------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------+
```

Now, for further grouping the data, I need to join Hours and Minutes columns in one column for getting output like this

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
| CompLast_SignON_datetime | comp_accidentdate_time | Duty_hours |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
| 16-12-2021 04:08         | 16-12-2021 05:10       | 1.02       |
| 17-12-2021 14:20         | 17-12-2021 20:00       | 5.40       |
| 18-12-2021 12:15         | 18-12-2021 15:25       | 3.10       |
| 22-12-2021 06:00         | 22-12-2021 12:34       | 6.34       |
| 25-12-2021 11:30         | 25-12-2021 21:40       | 10.10      |
| 26-12-2021 21:00         | 27-12-2021 02:50       | 5.50       |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: *Please* use whitespace and linebreaks when writing code. One long line is never easy to read.

Comment: Are you sure you want to just concatenate hours and minutes to appear as a decimal? 5 hours 40 minutes is  5.67 hours

Comment: If you have an integer and divide by another integer, you get an integer. There is no need to use `ROUND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting both hours and mins to varchar and concate both to make new column.

```
SELECT 
    CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) / 60), 2, 1)) + '.' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) - CONVERT(INT,(ROUND((DATEDIFF(minute, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time) / 60), 2, 1)) * 60)), '00')) AS 'Duty_hours' 
FROM Safety_SIMS
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Got it! Edited.

Comment: It is working for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're showing the minutes instead of a fraction of the hours, it'll be more natural to use `:` instead of `.`

Then you can use DATEDIFF and FORMAT to get difference in hours & minutes as a string.

> ```
> select *
> , [Duty_hours] = format(datediff(hour, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time), '00')
>                  + format(comp_accidentdate_time - CompLast_SignON_datetime, ':mm')
> from Safety_SIMS;
> ```

| CompLast_SignON_datetime | comp_accidentdate_time | Duty_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-16 04:08 | 2021-12-16 05:10 | 01:02 |
| 2021-12-17 14:20 | 2021-12-17 20:00 | 06:40 |
| 2021-12-18 12:15 | 2021-12-18 15:25 | 03:10 |
| 2021-12-22 06:00 | 2021-12-22 12:34 | 06:34 |
| 2021-12-25 11:30 | 2021-12-25 21:40 | 10:10 |
| 2021-12-26 21:00 | 2021-12-27 02:50 | 05:50 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=086ce73c2322cf1dc6db3105112e388a)*

It can be simplified

```
select *
, [Duty_hours] = format(comp_accidentdate_time - CompLast_SignON_datetime, 'HH:mm')
from Safety_SIMS;
```

But then you're assuming the difference is always less than a day.

And here's a version that calculates the time difference as a decimal.

```
select *
, [Duty_hours] = datediff(hour, CompLast_SignON_datetime, comp_accidentdate_time)
                 + cast(format(comp_accidentdate_time - CompLast_SignON_datetime, '.mm') as decimal(10,2))
from Safety_SIMS;
```

Comment: In decimal form, it is easy to group data to get no. of Cases between 00-02, 02-04, 04-06 hours, which is difficult to achieve in hh:mm format.

Comment: Is it really? `where Duty_hours between '01:00' and '06:00'` works fine. Because of the leading 0, the character sort is fine.  And btw, you can just replace the `:` by a dot in this solution.

Comment: You are right, just check by replacing ':' with a dot. It is the simplest solution to my issue. you are rock, thanks.

Comment: However, in case the difference is more than a day, it will not work.